# Wrong behaviour of labels from `cut` using `dplyr::rowwise`?

Tags: r, dplyr

In `R` and using `dplyr`, I need to `cut` values in one one column using non-constant (not unique) `breaks`, these being defined, for each row, by values in other columns of a same data frame. Hence I use `rowwise`. While the `breaks` seem to be functionally working (i.e. updated for each line), the `labels` do not appear to be consistent.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(10)
myDF = data.frame(a=runif(5, min=0.3, max=0.7), 
                  bmin = rep(0, 5), 
                  bmid = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4),
                  bmax = rep(1, 5))

myDF %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(grp1 = cut(a, breaks=c(bmin, bmid, bmax)),
                              grp2 = cut(a, breaks=c(bmin, bmid, bmax), 
                                         labels=c(paste(bmin, bmid, sep='-'),
                                                  paste(bmid, bmax, sep='-'))),
                              grp3 = cut(a, breaks=c(bmin, bmid, bmax), 
                                         labels=c(1, 2)))

#           a  bmin  bmid  bmax    grp1   grp2   grp3
#       (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)  (fctr) (fctr) (fctr)
# 1 0.3901746     0   0.5     1 (0,0.5]  0-0.5      1
# 2 0.4098122     0   0.3     1 (0.5,1]  0.5-1      2
# 3 0.4089220     0   0.6     1 (0,0.5]  0-0.5      1
# 4 0.5463317     0   0.7     1 (0,0.5]  0-0.5      1
# 5 0.4718686     0   0.4     1 (0.5,1]  0.5-1      2
```

In this example, one can see e.g. on line 2 that the `cut` is functionnally correct (i.e., value `0.3` was properly used as cut point `bmid` instead of `0.5` from the first line), but the resulting label is wrong (i.e. `(0.5, 1]` does actually not contain the value `0.4098122` and `0.5` was indeed not the cut point).

`grp2` is an attempt to manually set the labels, failing too, meaning that a manual `breaks`-independent solution as in `grp3` appears to be the only way forward...

In short, `rowwise` does not seem to apply to the labels, but well to the cut points...

Am I missing anything, or is this a wrong behaviour?
How can I label my intervals on a rowwise basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to build a factor column where each row has different levels/labels. This is not really possible with factors. The `mutate` seems to be trying to harmonize all the factor labels for you which is producing this odd effect. It's not unique to `cut()` see also

```
data.frame(z=c("a","b","c")) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(g=factor(z))
#        z      g
#   (fctr) (fctr)
# 1      a      a
# 2      b      a
# 3      c      a
```

One workaround would be to return character values rather than factor values.

```
myDF %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(grp1 = as.character(cut(a, breaks=c(bmin, bmid, bmax))))
```

Comment: That would probably be my issue as well in my previous situations. Thanks.

Comment: Wrapping the cut function in as.character does not help, were you able to figure out an alternative solution?